# applying different style to specific input button

Tags: html, css

check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dyk2n3b/)
I want to apply different style to second button. I guess there is just a different sytax. Help.

```
<input type="button">
<input type="button" class="button2">
```

I dont want to use id, beacause it's to be used for some other purpose.

Comment: Try implementing inline style for your html element

Comment: Why can’t you simply use the `id` that you are going to use anyway? There’s no law against using the `id` of an element for as many purposes as you like.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela There are lot of "second" buttons, which will be added dynamically, and have different id's.. so I thnk id will have no use...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Specificity** is the means by which a browser decides which property values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied.
>   Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of
>   selectors of different sorts.

You can specificity the css selector using 'has' class add apply the rule to input button elements with class `.button2`:

```css
input[type="button"] {
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
[type='button'].button2 {
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="button">

<input type="button" class="button2">
```

Also take a look [**Specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Attribute selectors have the same weight as classes, so it would suffice to do `input.button2` : http://jsfiddle.net/0dyk2n3b/5/

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="button">

<input type="button" class="button2">


input[type="button"]{
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
}
input[type="button"].button2{
     width: 100px;
     background: black;

 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0dyk2n3b/1/

Comment: This is a correct answer, but a good answer is accompanied with a short explanation that describes the idea (and often links to a reference).

Comment: Since the person who asked the question was very close solving the problem I assumed an explanation was unnecessary. But maybe that's just how I see it!

Answer (score 2):

Check this
http://jsfiddle.net/0dyk2n3b/2/

```
 input.button2{
 width: 100px;
 background: black;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation on Arvind's answer, but without use of important:

```css
input[type="button"] {
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
}
input[type="button"].button2 {
  width: 100px;
  background: black ;
}
```

```html
<input type="button">

<input type="button" class="button2">
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do this.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/0dyk2n3b/4/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button">
<input type="button" class="button2">
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="button"]{
    width: 500px;
    background: red;
}
input[type="button"].button2{
    width: 100px;
    background: green;    
}
```